# Помогите доработать код

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите доработать данный код:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userinfo LIMIT 1") or die('MYSQL 
ERROR:'.mysql_error());
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
echo $myrow[name];
```

Мне нужно сделать типа мельницу, что бы он из базы выводил random, при обновлении что бы всегда менялась запись кто может помочь ?!
Но очень хотелось что бы через js, и он менялся допустим каждые 30 секунд

Comment: ORDER BY RAND(), но эт плохо.

Comment: а как можно сделать что бы было хорошо, и допустим менялось каждые 30 секунд

Comment: Ajax вам в помощь, но это довольно сложная технология для новичков

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM userinfo LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or trigger_error('MYSQL 
ERROR:'.mysqli_error($link)." ".$query);
if($result){
$myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
} 
echo $myrow[name];
```

Советую Ваш код заменить на этот!

$link - подключение к БД через mysqli_connect

Comment: У человека модуль mysql используется, но суть я думаю такая : не используйте модуль mysql) Я уже года полтора наверно на PDO_MySQL сижу.

Comment: Я сам не знаю как примерно всё заменить, если вам не трудно будет можете дать код уже с подключением к базе данных, мне желательно через таймер что бы каждые 30 менялось